# How to return a list of all points earned and add/remove a role

Tags: c#, sql-server, discord, discord.net

I've built a reaction based voting system which allows for users in my discord server to vote for someone, and based on the vote they are given they will get x amount of points E.G 5 star rating gives 10 points.

All these figures are then added to a SQL-Server Database along with the person who voted for them and the `DateTime` the vote was cast.

What i am now trying to figure out is how can i add/remove roles for people who are being voted for. For example once a member recieves 100 points they are a assigned X role and if they drop below 100 remove the role is removed.

I'm struggling to figure out how i would write the `SQL Function` to get this information - i think i'll be confident enough to write the c# to accompany this.

Fields in my Table are

- Sherpa - Person who has been voted for
- VotedBy - Person who voted
- Date - Date the vote was cast
- Points - The amount of points awarded

Example of how the data is being stored to the Database

```
var message = (RestUserMessage) await channel.GetMessageAsync(SherpaReact.CatchReaction);
if (reaction.MessageId == SherpaReact.CatchReaction && reaction.UserId == SherpaReact.UserReaction) {
 SqlCommand command;
 command = new SqlCommand($ @ "EXECUTE dbo.AddSherpa @Points = @@Points, @Sherpa = @@Sherpa, @VotedBy = @@VotedBy, @Date = @@Date", StaticObjects._connection);

 if (reaction.Emote.Name == "1\u20e3") {
  await message.DeleteAsync();

  SqlParameter PointsParam = new SqlParameter {
   ParameterName = "@@Points",
    Value = (long) - 8
  };
  command.Parameters.Add(PointsParam);

  SqlParameter SherpaParam = new SqlParameter {
   ParameterName = "@@Sherpa",
    Value = (long) SherpaReact.Sherpa.Id
  };
  command.Parameters.Add(SherpaParam);

  SqlParameter VotedByParam = new SqlParameter {
   ParameterName = "@@VotedBy",
    Value = (long) SherpaReact.UserReaction
  };
  command.Parameters.Add(VotedByParam);

  SqlParameter DateParam = new SqlParameter {
   ParameterName = "@@Date",
    Value = DateTime.Now
  };
  command.Parameters.Add(DateParam);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();

  var sherpa = SherpaReact.Sherpa.Nickname.Contains("(") ? SherpaReact.Sherpa.Nickname.Substring(0, SherpaReact.Sherpa.Nickname.IndexOf("(") - 1) : SherpaReact.Sherpa.Nickname;
  EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder() {
   Title = "Vote Accepted",
    Description = $ "Thanks for voting for {sherpa}",
    Color = new Color(127, 127, 0)
  };
  IUserMessage msg = await channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: eb.Build());
  _ = Task.Run(() => DeleteMessagesAsync(msg));
 }
```

I've have made a simple function just to return a SUM of all the points that a Sherpa has received so far, but i just can't get my head around how to do this next bit if anyone can point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSherpaPoints]
(
)
RETURNS @returntable TABLE
(
    Sherpa BIGINT,
    Points BIGINT
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT @returntable
    SELECT
        [Sherpa],
        SUM([Points]) AS [PointsSum]
    FROM
        [dbo].[SherpaVotes]
    WHERE
        [Sherpa] = Sherpa
    GROUP BY
        [Sherpa]
    ORDER BY
        [PointsSum] DESC
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: It would be lovely if you could reindent that code

Comment: You need to add parameter @Sherpa BIGINT and use in where condition in function. So, you will get your expected result when you call function.

Comment: @CaiusJard - done

Comment: @JIKEN - not sure i follow sorry

Comment: Check this [3. Multi-statement Table-Valued User-Defined Function](https://sqlhints.com/tag/multi-statement-table-valued-user-defined-function/). It will help you to resolve your query.

Comment: Why a function? Stored procedure that does a select would probably be more appropriate in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something with a case :

```
SELECT
   Sherpa,
   CASE 
     WHEN Points < 100 THEN 'NoRole'
     WHEN Points >= 100 AND Points < 200 THEN 'Role1'
     WHEN Points >= 200 AND Points < 300 THEN 'Role2' -- And so on...
     END as Role
FROM @Results;
```

For as small number of role.
If you have a lot you should create a Role table with min and max values of point and compute it accordingly.

EDIT:
This should work as per your comment

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSherpaPoints]
(
)
RETURNS @returntable TABLE
(
    Sherpa BIGINT,
    Role nvarchar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT @returntable
    SELECT
        [Sherpa],
         CASE 
             WHEN SUM(Points) < 100 THEN 'NoRole'
             WHEN SUM(Points) >= 100 AND SUM(Points) < 200 THEN 'Role1'
             WHEN SUM(Points) >= 200 AND SUM(Points) < 300 THEN 'Role2' -- And so on...
        END as Role
    FROM
        [dbo].[SherpaVotes]
    WHERE
        [Sherpa] = Sherpa
    GROUP BY
        [Sherpa]
    ORDER BY
        [PointsSum] DESC
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this will only look at individual lines though?, each Sherpa may have been voted for numerous times so will need to return the SUM of the points earned like i've done in my example

Comment: Edited to reflect your question

Comment: Perfect!, thanks :), i just needed to update the ORDER BY field to Role instead of PointsSum